# How to calculate Data from few columns of WebTable using Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have to calculate the webtable data.

A WebTable has 6 columns and 20 Rows. We have to calculate

On **Form-1**

```
addition of data in column1   (from row1 to row20)

addition of data in column2  ( from row1 to row20)

addition of data in column4= (from row1 to row20)

addition of data in column5= (from row1 to row20)
```

Similarly data on Form-2, and Form-3 with 6 columns and 20 Rows

But, On **Form-4**

6 columns available on that page but Rows are not 20. Rows count is not specific it might be anything less than 20.

**Condition-1**:

If  addition of , then don’t count the values from that row. So, please suggest me how to program this in Java.

Page navigation point is at bottom
when Form-1 is open, page navigation is as shown below

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - >
```

when Form-2 is open, page navigation is as shown below

```
<- 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 ->
```

when Form-4 is open, page navigation is as shown below

```
< - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4
```

I want to calculate the data of column1 from "**Form-1,Form-2,Form-3 & Form-4**".

Thanks in Advance.
Vivek

Comment: Please Go through [ask]

Comment: What code have you tried and what was the result?